# Nanopore variant calling

Tags: variant-calling, nanopore

So far I haven't done any variant calling as such. Nanopore I have used for 16s microbiome data.

Now My question/doubt so how do I proceed for nano-pore virus sequencing data

Steps:

- I get fast5 files
- The i perform base-calling using guppy
- Get fastq files

Now after doing the above is it possible to use variant calling that is used for Ilumina once I get the fastq files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools for illumina are not really suitable for long read sequencing. For nanopore data I would suggest [LongShot](https://github.com/pjedge/longshot), [Clair3](https://github.com/HKU-BAL/Clair3) or [DeepVariant-PEPPER](https://github.com/kishwarshafin/pepper).

Answer (score -1):

Sure it is possible, but I guess it won't be more reliable than a method specifically designed for Nanopore. But if you use Nanopore I guess accuracy is not your main concern.